# How Can I Curve My Object Like In The Reference Provided

Tags: modeling

[image: Effect I Would Like To Get]

[image: My Object]

I'm using an array modifier for the object and i need to curve it like in the reference. I'm not worried about the pattern on the end, I just need to curve my existing object.

Here's my blender file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a circle curve and keep only one half (select 3 vertices and *Delete > Segments*):

[image]

Extrude to get this shape, rotate in *Edit* mode to align the way you wan, put its origin at its geometry:

[image]

Put your object at the same position, give it a *Curve* modifier, choose the curve as *Curve Object*:

[image]